Flutter TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>
I am creating a Flutter app using Flutter News template and when I try to retrieve the feed for a specific category, I keep getting this error: _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast).
When I try to switch categories using the tabs in the app UI, I do get the log with the full JSON from my endpoint. I do need the full JSON and not part of it, so that I can extract all the information I need for the app UI.
I added some logs to get a better understanding of the problem. I also tried adding as Map<String, dynamic> after the json() call, but it did not help.
The relevant code:
Future<FeedResponse> getFeed({
    Category? category,
    int? limit,
    int? offset,
  }) async {
    final uri =
        Uri.parse('https://myappurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=28');
    final response = await _httpClient.get(
      uri,
      // headers: await _getRequestHeaders(),
    );

    if (response.body is List<dynamic>) {
      log('MyLog: Received a list of posts');
    } else {
      log('MyLog: Unexpected response format:');
    }

    final body = response.json(); //This line throws the error

    if (response.statusCode != HttpStatus.ok) {
      throw MyappApiRequestFailure(
        body: body,
        statusCode: response.statusCode,
      );
    }

    return FeedResponse.fromJson(body);
  }

extension on http.Response {
  Map<String, dynamic> json() {
    try {
      final decodedBody = utf8.decode(bodyBytes);
      // log('MyLog decoded ${jsonDecode(decodedBody)}');
      return jsonDecode(decodedBody) as Map<String, dynamic>; //this line is also marked in the error
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        MyappApiMalformedResponse(error: error),
        stackTrace,
      );
    }
  }
}

The error I get in the debug console:
GetFeedFailure (GetFeedFailure(Instance of 'MyappApiMalformedResponse'))
#0      _extension#0.json (package:myapp_api/src/client/myapp_api_client.dart:370:38)
#1      MyappApiClient.getFeed (package:myapp_api/src/client/myapp_api_client.dart:176:19)
myapp_api_client.dart:176
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      NewsRepository.getFeed (package:news_repository/src/news_repository.dart:76:14)
news_repository.dart:76
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FeedBloc._updateFeed (package:myapp/feed/bloc/feed_bloc.dart:54:24)
feed_bloc.dart:54
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure>.handleEvent (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:229:13) bloc.dart:229
<asynchronous suspension>


clearly jsonDecode(decodedBody) is a List, not a Map.  Can you print it out on an error to see what it actually was?
